# monitor folders on iis

Tags: php, iis

I'm running PHP on IIS (can't change that) and need a php script to run every time a file is added to a watched folder. Furthermore I need said script to know the name of the file.

After fighting it a while I have currently solved it by using Transform Manager, and then send the info by notifications. While that does i fact do the trick it also deletes the file.

So my question is this: how do I stop it from deleting my files or is there an overall better method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have a long-running script with a `while` loop to check either the contents or the last-modified time of the folder.

Comment: wouldn't doing that in PHP put a huge strain on the server?

Comment: Not all all. Put a 1/10/60 second sleep during each loop.